# Spring MVC with Boot: "There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

So I'm new to Spring and I've so far gotten a simple web API running connected to a MongoDB database, but I'm having trouble generating just plain old views using .jsp or .html files. I've tried a variety of different approaches: `InternalResourceViewResolver`, `XmlViewResolver`, returning Strings instead of `ModelAndView` objects, nothing seems to be working for me. I have the following code:

**Edit**: here is a git repo with my project: https://github.com/jwallp/Spring-Test

As the above project is, I am getting a white label error upon going to `/index` which says:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Circular view path [index]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/index] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

**Edit**: So I managed to get the view to finally load by using `spring.view.prefix` and `spring.view.suffix` instead of `spring.mvc.view.prefix` and such, and by moving my `WEB-INF` directory from my project root to inside `<project root>/src/main/webapp/`. I just wanted to know, if my `WEB-INF` directory is contained within another directory, will it still function as intended (making its contents not directly visible)?

Comment: Using spring.view.prefix in application.properties with Eclipse STS , Spring boot 2.0.2, gives :  "spring.view.prefix  is an unkwown property"

Answer (score 5):

Spring Boot has limited support for JSP, because of its use of an embedded servlet container. From the [Spring Boot reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.x/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations):

> When running a Spring Boot application that uses an embedded servlet
>   container (and is packaged as an executable archive), there are some
>   limitations in the JSP support.
>
> With Tomcat it should work if you use war packaging, i.e. an
>   executable war will work, and will also be deployable to a standard
>   container (not limited to, but including Tomcat). An executable jar
>   will not work because of a hard coded file pattern in Tomcat. Jetty
>   does not currently work as an embedded container with JSPs.

[Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp) is a basic example of using jsp in spring boot application.

Comment: Oh well thank you for informing me of that, I didn't know. I am using war packaging now, but the problem still persists. I saw that example too, my project looks almost identical to it, yet the page still won't load.

Comment: Thanks a ton didn't know that, was struggling since yesterday, works just fine with war deployment

Answer (score 3):

Hope you have the JSP libraries in your classpath. If you are using maven, including the following dependencies in `pom.xml` will have those:

```
    <!-- For using JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- If you want to use JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Also, you may need to put this line at the top of the JSP file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
```

**Update**

Doing the following changes to your project at GitHub worked in my environment:

1. Move the WEB-INF folder into `src/main/webapp`. That's the place for it.
2. In `application.properties` replace

   ```
   spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/pages/
   spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
   ```

   with

   ```
   spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/pages/
   spring.view.suffix: .jsp
   ```

   Seems the former will work with Spring Boot [1.3](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-view-resolvers), but not not with the [current stable release](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-view-resolvers).

Comment: I had already included Jasper and JSTL, I hadn't used that line of code, and I tried including it on the first line of my `index.jsp`, still nothing.

Comment: Things look good to my eyes, then. Could be something silly - difficult to guess without looking at the complete source code. Did you try changing the packaging to war?

Comment: If you are still struggling with it, I can give it a shot if I you provide me the complete source code of a minimal sample project with the issue. You can upload it at GitHub or somewhere.

Comment: I have changed packaging to war and still no luck. Here is a link to my project: https://github.com/jwallp/Spring-Test

Comment: Oh! I now see your edited question that you had already fixed it. I should have seen that before giving my time into downloading and testing it in my env. Or, you could have put a comment here as soon as you did it. I don't think putting your WEB-INF directory elsewhere would work. There may be some way to configure it, thought.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Following:

```
package hello;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

    @Controller
    public class IndexController
    {
        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String index()
        {
            return "index";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have done something similar to this (I simply used "/index" where you used "/") and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this problem at work while upgrading an older application to Spring Boot. What we did:

1. The prefix and suffix mappings as given above for `application.properties` (though our prefix was just `/WEB-INF/`).
2. Moved our CSS, JavaScript, HTML files to a resources\static folder. We had subdirectories under that for each type.
3. Places where `window.open("somefile.jsp")` was used, was changed to `window.open("somevalue.do")` where `somevalue` mapped to a `@RequestMapping` value and the `setViewName` for the `ModelAndView` of that method mapped to the previous jsp. Where there was a `window.open("somefile.html")` we changed it to map to `window.open("includes/somefile.html")` where includes is a subdirectory in our resources/static tree.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem few times. It was because I put /WEB-INF/ in /src/main/java folder. Latest I created separate path for the INF file in /src/main/webapp and I was able to run my application correctly and displayed the text in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Following jsp files relocation can solve the problem. I solved my problem this way:

Move the .jsp files to:

```
"src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp".
```

Make sure the application.properties file contains:

```
spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Your controller class should be like:

```
   @Controller
    public class IndexController
     {
         @RequestMapping("/")
         public String index()
          {
             return "index";
         }
      }
```

If you are using maven, include the following dependencies in pom.xml

```
<!-- For using JSP -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- If you want to use JSTL -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It should then work.

Answer (score 0):

I added one line to my application.properties file.

```
server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=hk2-utils.jar,javax.annotation-api.jar,javax.inject.jar,hk2-api.jar,config-types.jar,hk2-core.jar,hk2-config.jar,tiger-types.jar,validation-api.jar,jboss-logging.jar,classmate.jar,hk2-locator.jar,javassist.jar,hk2-runlevel.jar,class-model.jar,asm-all-repackaged.jar
```

It should then run.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `mvn spring-boot:run`

It's worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough I have tried many ways to fix this issue, couldn't find perfect solution.

If you are using Intellij IDEA : do not try to run Spring Boot application(with dynamic .jsp views) with the IDE's run ▶︎ button.

```
$ cd {PROJECT_FOLDER}

$ ls //Make sure that you are in the same folder where pom.xml resides
and then run below command

$ mvn spring-boot:run
```

Now your application should be served at localhost:8080.

Answer (score 0):

i have faced the same problem and my solution was replacing the

spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/pages/

spring.view.suffix: .jsp

with a configuration class like this. it worked for me!

```
package com.rbc.sample.user.login.sample;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;


@Configuration
public class WebConfig {


    public static final String RESOLVER_PREFIX= "/WEB_INF/jsp/";
    public static final String RESOLVER_SUFIX=".jsp";


    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver=new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix(RESOLVER_PREFIX);
        viewResolver.setSuffix(RESOLVER_SUFIX);

        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```