# javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/error] again - Spring Cloud

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

I am using the **Git based Spring Cloud** Project. In this project, I pointed out to the https://github.com/rseroter/pluralsight-spring-cloudconfig-wa-tolls.

When I simply launched the URL: http://localhost:8888/actuator/s1rates/default or 
http://localhost:8888/s1rates/default, got the below error.

Could you please guide why this error is coming ?

I already went through below URL's:

1. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2001
2. [Circular View path error Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697663/circular-view-path-error-spring-boot/41918545)

But it didn't helped me either.

Error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering(InternalResourceView.java:209) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:147) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:314) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:472) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:395) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:177) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_162]
```

**SpringcloudM2ConfigserverGitApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class SpringcloudM2ConfigserverGitApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringcloudM2ConfigserverGitApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8888
  error:
    whitelabel:
      enabled: false


spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/rseroter/pluralsight-spring-cloudconfig-wa-tolls
```

**Error Screen Shot:**

[image]

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 7):

Had the same exception and couldn't find answer, so here's what I figured out.
When you disable `spring.error.whitelabel.enabled`, then when there is exception Spring tries to find /error mapping. When it doesn't find one, uses internal error handler, which resolves to one of error html pages. When it cannot find those pages, throws exception, and you can guess - tries to find /error mapping. Hence circular error.
So there are two solutions.

1. Add your controller which implements ErrorController with @RequestMapping("/error"), and any logic you need there
2. Add custom html error pages. E.g. `src/main/resources/static/error/4xx.html` and/or `src/main/resources/static/error/5xx.html`

Both worked for me.

Here is example of first approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/25362790/4252764 .