# "Circular view path would dispatch back to the current handler URL." when using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, thymeleaf

When using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf, when trying to accessing the /home URL I am getting the following:

**ServletException**: Circular view path [home]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/home] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>watchlist</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>watchlist</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

main/java/com.demo.WatchlistApplication.java:

```java
package com.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WatchlistApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WatchlistApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

main/java/com.demo.controller.HomeController.java:

```java
package com.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public ModelAndView home() {

        return new ModelAndView("home");
    }
}
```

main/resources/templates/home.html:

```html
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1, shrink-to-fit = no">
    <title>Web app</title>
</head>

<body>

<p th:text="'Hello world'"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

Annotate you controller class "HomeController" with annotation @RestController instead @Controller.

Seems duplicate of [Circular View path error Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697663/circular-view-path-error-spring-boot)

Comment: That did not work, after changing it to @RestController, the same exception occurs.

Comment: @MaximeEsnol I created Spring boot project with same content you mentioned above, its working fine. I hope you do not have any other configuration. I added application.properties file in resource folder and set "spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true". If I set it to false I get same exception as yours.

Comment: Adding that flag fixed the problem! Thank you!

Comment: This has worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

For springboot 2.6.0, Try **controller**:

```java
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home() {

        return "home"; // be same as the template file name (without suffix)
    }
}
```

You should have `resources/templates/home.html`.

Make sure the `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` has been downloaded successfully.