# Java controller always return a 404 no matter what I do

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, tomcat

I was following an example from the spring boot documentation and the java controller always returns a 404 for some reason

This is what I tried

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller // This means that this class is a Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/demo") // This means URL's start with /demo (after Application path)
public class MainController {
  @Autowired // This means to get the bean called userRepository
         // Which is auto-generated by Spring, we will use it to handle the data
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @PostMapping(path="/add") // Map ONLY POST Requests
  public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestParam String name
      , @RequestParam String email) {
    // @ResponseBody means the returned String is the response, not a view name
    // @RequestParam means it is a parameter from the GET or POST request

    User n = new User();
    n.setName(name);
    n.setEmail(email);
    userRepository.save(n);
    return "Saved";
  }

  @GetMapping(path="/all")
  public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
    // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
    return userRepository.findAll();
  }
}
```

which is the example given by spring boot here https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

Then I also tried

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public class GreetingClass {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String getGreeting() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

.pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.braintobytes</groupId>
    <artifactId>Finance_microservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Finance_microservice</name>
    <description>Finance service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I know this is weird, I set up everything as instructed on the page but apparently nothing works, and I also checked other questions similar to this none of them answer my question.

It does seem that the tomcat server is hit, because it says when I make a call

```
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 9 ms
```

but then I get with this call curl 'http://localhost:8080/demo/greeting' and with 'http://localhost:8080/demo/all'

curl : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Logs (the file path is removed on the first line):

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.2.RELEASE)

2020-08-31 08:19:16.508  INFO 20708 --- [           main] c.b.f.FinanceMicroserviceApplication     : Starting FinanceMicroserviceApplication on DESKTOP-A65224I with PID 20708 ()
2020-08-31 08:19:16.510  INFO 20708 --- [           main] c.b.f.FinanceMicroserviceApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-08-31 08:19:17.096  INFO 20708 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-08-31 08:19:17.101  INFO 20708 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-08-31 08:19:17.101  INFO 20708 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
2020-08-31 08:19:17.150  INFO 20708 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-08-31 08:19:17.150  INFO 20708 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 618 ms
2020-08-31 08:19:17.465  INFO 20708 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-08-31 08:19:17.675  INFO 20708 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-08-31 08:19:17.681  INFO 20708 --- [           main] c.b.f.FinanceMicroserviceApplication     : Started FinanceMicroserviceApplication in 1.328 seconds (JVM running for 1.835)
2020-08-31 08:20:21.893  INFO 20708 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-08-31 08:20:21.893  INFO 20708 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-08-31 08:20:21.905  INFO 20708 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 12 ms
```

Response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-08-31T13:20:21.930+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/demo/greeting"
}
```

This works if I do this:

https://github.com/BraintoByte/Test_App_Stack/tree/master/demo

**Different example:**

I have attached a different example with hirarchy exactly the same but business logic omitted:

Code in controller:

```
package com.braintobytes.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.braintobytes.data.Currency;
import com.braintobytes.data.repository.CurrencyRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public class CurrencyController {
    @Autowired
    private CurrencyRepository currencyRepository;
    
    @GetMapping("/currency")
    public String getCurrency() {
        return "currency";
    }
}
```

Project hierarchy:

[image]

Same exact pom and in application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mydatabase
spring.datasource.username=myusername
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
```

Comment: Can you post your **pom.xml** ?

Comment: did you set any context path for your application?
Add: if your program runs successfully, check your log, you may see the whole base link for your app excluding your controller's path

Comment: @Brain Bytes Can you add the logs. It would be easy to identify the problem with logs

Comment: @AvijitBarua I posted it sorry

Comment: @Sahit I posted them all I have

Comment: @user404 I cannot see it, I can only see that it has been hit and it's returning a not found error

This is what happen when I send the request 2020-08-31 08:20:21.905  INFO 20708 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 12 ms

Comment: Let me guess the controller you added is in a package not covered by the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class.

Comment: @BrainBytes, seems ok. don't know other config though. Can you please provide link of your actual project you are trying to run in your ide if not yet resolved?

Comment: @BrainBytes can you please give a screenshot of your project structure ?

Comment: Notice this on MainController "@RequestMapping(path="/demo") // This means URL's start with /demo (after Application path)"

Comment: @javaguy so http://localhost:8080/demo/greeting

Comment: @javaguy I tried all of them nothing same thing

Comment: @BrainBytes Since this is a sample project, push it to a github repo and share the link. Then people might understand what is going wrong.

Comment: @Sahit This is a modified project, it reflects the same as the example above, I am not putting it on github

Comment: @javaguy that does not work

Comment: @M.Deinum how do I know that?

Comment: @javaguy this works if I do this https://github.com/BraintoByte/Test_App_Stack/tree/master/demo

Comment: show please your project structure

Comment: @EvgeniyKalashnikov I posted the structure

Comment: @javaguy I posted the project structure

Comment: `@RestController` works for most cases when you just try [to return a string or JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697663/circular-view-path-error-spring-boot/72825249#72825249).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so none of the suggestions above worked, we were on the right path though.

Changing the structure as so worked:

[image]

There was also a pathing problem in the application.properties and thus I changed as so:

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}

To:

jdbc:mysql://localhost

And finally:

```
package com.braintobytes.finance.data.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.braintobytes.finance.data.Currency;

public interface CurrencyRepository extends CrudRepository<Currency, Integer> {

}
```

Woah!

Comment: I am happy to hear that at least the answers help you to find the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your controller is in package - com.example.accessingdatamysql

Spring boot startup log shows your main application class c.b.f.FinanceMicroserviceApplication is in another non related package hierarchy.

Spring boot recommends to locate main application class in a root package above other classes so that the component scan works out of box.

If you keep package com.example as root package and move your main application class FinanceMicroserviceApplication to it then everything should work as expected.

If you don't follow Spring boot recommendation for package hierarchy then you need to explicitly specify packages to scan with @SpringBootApplication annotation.

Comment: I did, package com.braintobytes.finance;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FinanceMicroserviceApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(FinanceMicroserviceApplication.class, args);
 }
}

Comment: @BrainBytes replace "package com.braintobytes.finance; " with "package com.example;"  then com.example package will become your root package in hierarchy and component scan will work out of box.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone whom facing this wired issue, just move the main class of spring boot to become in the main package of the application, something like that, my main class named, Demo2Application

[image]

Comment: This has already been answered as per below